# Data is not visible on remote Oracle 18 XE connection

Tags: database, oracle, remote-connection

I have created Oracle Database on windows machine , with test table.

`CREATE TABLE TESTUSER  ( NAME VARCHAR2(20)  , LASTNAME VARCHAR2(20)  );`

and inserted data into this table

```
insert into testuser(name, lastname) VALUES('Jon','Doe');
```

Then remote connected to this database from another machine, connected and authenticated successfully, I can see table and columns, but when I query the table, it is empty.

Have anyone faced similar issue? will much appreciate the hint or correct direction.

Comment: no, i did not. should i ?

Comment: guess it is my absence of knowledge of oracle database, usually i was using it on `Linux` machine and in never required `COMMIT WORK` statement. seems there is some difference between `Linux` and 'Windows' maybe?

Comment: There's no difference in the database. Might be a difference in the client software that you are using; some can be set to commit transactions by default. Some commands (like `CREATE` or `ALTER`) will also issue an implicit commit. Regardless of how you do it, transactions must *always* be committed if you expect the data to be visible to other sessions.

Comment: yes, I'm using SQL developer